# Access variable with name from string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, variables

```
 @result.instance_variable_get("#{@most}_max_count".to_sym)
```

`@most` is a single-digit string, for instance `i`. This code bit gives the error

```
`i_max_count' is not allowed as an instance variable name
```

(What I am trying to access is `@result.i_max_count`)

edit:
What I want to do is to set the value of @result.i_max_count to something.

Class for @result is pretty much empty:

```
class Result < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessor :least, :most
end
```

Comment: can you paste the class for @result object

Comment: There is no instance variable `i_max_count` for the `Result` class.. hence the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter of instance_variable_get should be valid instance variable name: @i_max_count for example.
So you can slightly change your code:

```
@result.instance_variable_get("@#{@most}_max_count".to_sym)
```

But question has tag "ruby-on-rails" so probably you are working with Hash. This way you can try that (thx for @FrederickCheung):

```
@result["#{@most}_max_count"]
```

or even this way:

```
@result.instance_variable_get("@attributes")["#{@most}_max_count"]
```

Or using eval:

```
eval("@rezult.#{@most}_max_count")
```

Comment: why the eval in the hash case ?

Comment: `eval("@result.#{@most}_max_count")` gives the correct value, but how can I change this value addressing it in the same way?

Comment: Your eval string + `@result.update_attribute("#{@most}_max_count", 20)` solved my problem. Thanks!

Comment: @FrederickCheung, of course, Hash is a Object, so i add "instance_variable_get way" to my answer. But in case of Hash i prefer eval - it gives more readable code.

Comment: It's completely unnecessary - send is faster and safer, and in this case result["#{@most}_max_count"] would work too.

Answer (score 0):

The instance variable names always have to start with an `@ sigil` . The below snippet shows usage

**`Eg`**

```
class Ankit  
 def initialize(name)
  @name = name
 end
end
```

**`UPDATED:`**

```
1.9.3p392 :033 > a = Ankit.new("ankit")
 => #<Ankit:0x007fb3c39c79e8 @name="ankit"> 
1.9.3p392 :034 > a.instance_variable_get("@name")
 => "ankit"
```

**`In your case check 2 things`**

1. Is @i_max_count set?
2. If yes than use it `obj.instance_variable_get("@i_max_count")`

Comment: why the eval and not just `a.instance_variable_get("@name")`

Comment: @FrederickCheung: Apologies, i just drafted the answer keeping the symbol in mind and to treat the symbol string ":@name" used eval.  This will work directly too.  Updating the answer to come out of eval.  Thanks!

Comment: I am not trying to access  `@i_max_count` but the `@result.i_max_count` of the Result model, so this does not work.